# How to insert a serial wildcard even if the replacement string is same?

Tags: r

I am trying to digits that may be repeated with a serial variable `[VAR1], [VAR2], etc`

My attempt is the following.

```
equation = "((csv$Rrs550/csv$Rrs550)^-6.600000/(csv$Rrs670/csv$Rrs717)^-10.000000)^-10.000000*(csv$Rrs631/csv$Rrs550)^-10.000000/(csv$Rrs704/csv$Rrs631)^-10.000000"

mgsub::mgsub(equation,
  c("-6.600000", "-10.000000", "-10.000000", "-10.000000", "-10.000000"),
  sprintf("[VAR%d]", 1:5)
)
```

Output:

```
((csv$Rrs550/csv$Rrs550)^[VAR1]/(csv$Rrs670/csv$Rrs717)^[VAR2])^[VAR2]*(csv$Rrs631/csv$Rrs550)^[VAR2]/(csv$Rrs704/csv$Rrs631)^[VAR2]
```

Desired Output:

```
((csv$Rrs550/csv$Rrs550)^[VAR1]/(csv$Rrs670/csv$Rrs717)^[VAR2])^[VAR3]*(csv$Rrs631/csv$Rrs550)^[VAR4]/(csv$Rrs704/csv$Rrs631)^[VAR5]
```

This is to replace the VAR with a vector of number by increment values on any of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
from <- c("-6.600000", "-10.000000", "-10.000000", "-10.000000", "-10.000000")
to <- sprintf("[VAR%d]", 1:5)

for(i in seq_along(from)) equation <- sub(from[i], to[i], equation, fixed = TRUE)
equation
```

giving

```
[1] "((csv$Rrs550/csv$Rrs550)^[VAR1]/(csv$Rrs670/csv$Rrs717)^[VAR2])^[VAR3]*(csv$Rrs631/csv$Rrs550)^[VAR4]/(csv$Rrs704/csv$Rrs631)^[VAR5]"
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. However, I couldn't replace the other way round. Could you include it in your answer?

Comment: If you are trying to replace `to[i]` with `from[i]` instead of replacing `from[i]` with `to[i]` just switch them.